# why is this space happening around the navbar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

so i'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKV1IGahXqA but for some reason in the guide it shows this when background color is inserted
[image: Tutorial image1]

and mine is shown like this

[image: Mine]

This is my navbar.js where i'm building the navigation bar with a couple of icons and a searchBar

```
import "./navbar.scss";
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
import LanguageOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LanguageOutlined';
import DarkModeOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DarkModeOutlined';
import FullscreenOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FullscreenOutlined';
import NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/NotificationsNoneOutlined';
import ListOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ListOutlined';

const Navbar = () => {
  return(
      <div className="navbar">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            <SearchOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
          </div>
          <div className="items">
            <div className="item">
              <LanguageOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
              English
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <DarkModeOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <FullscreenOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <NotificationsNoneOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <ListOutlinedIcon className="icon"/>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is my navbar.scss were i'm styling navbar

```
.navbar{
  height: 67px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgb(231, 228, 228);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;

  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #333333;


    .search {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      border: 0.5px solid lightgray;


      input{
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        //background: transparent;
      }
    }

    .items{
      display:flex;
    }
  }
}
```

here is where im invoking navbarHome.js

```
import "./scss/home.scss";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "./navbar/Navbar";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="home">
          <Sidebar/>
          <div className="homeContainer">
              <Navbar/>
              <div>
                  Home container
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

What could be causing this issue ? I've searched all over the place and didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean the padding inside the navbar?

Comment: I mean that white spice around the grey block that i have in my code. Why won't it surround  everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving `.navbar` a fixed height of 67px but the content inside doesn't occupy as much space. In order to make the entire navbar grey either set `background: #333333` on the `.navbar` or set `height: 100%` on `.wrapper` element to make it fill the entire container.

Comment: Setting the background on the .navbar did the trick! thanks a lot for the help!